# Extra spacing in Chrome and Opera when selecting the text with the mouse

Tags: html, google-chrome, opera

I'm trying to get rid of the extra spacing when selecting the text with the mouse.

It happens when there are multiple lines and applies only to Chrome and Opera.

http://jsfiddle.net/gYWu4/2/

[image]

HTML code is as simple as:

```
test message<br>
test message
```

Please help.

Comment: Any reasons you want to get rid of it?

Comment: I don't see it copies any extra context. Take a look here http://jsfiddle.net/ahR6Y/. It returns `\n` character between lines, but this is what you get from `<br>`.

Comment: May be you should post more code/html we can use to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I see no behaviour specific to Chrome/Opera apart from the visual display of selected text. Look at http://jsfiddle.net/H9553/ in FF and IE and Opera Presto - each time, `$.text()` will give you three spaces in your test text, just like Chrome and Opera Blink. So is your problem the visual display of selected text, or (as per your comment) the behaviour of `text()`, which is NOT different to other browsers?